# How to publish a windows phone app after certification

Tags: windows-phone

I have my app certified and it is in status ready to be published(because i have selected **publish manually**).

Now how should i publish the app??
And how long will it take to get the app in app store after publishing??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN ([Understanding app and in-app product submission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206729%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)) it should be pretty easy:

> ***8. Ready to be published***
>
> Your submission has passed certification and is ready to be published
>   to users. If you are publishing manually, on your app’s or in-app
>   product’s **Lifecycle** view, click **Publish**.

Comment: what will be the name of the app in the app store?? the alias name or the xap file's name?

Comment: It's declared on app manifest. And you should confirm it during your submission.

Comment: Will the xap file's name be displayed on the app store?? Because i have mentioned it wrongly! will it be visible somewhere to the users??

Comment: No, I don't think so. Manifest file is much more important. At least it should.